# Having trouble getting cookies to work

Tags: jquery, cookies

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var lastsettings = $.cookie('location');

    if(lastsettings == "blue"){
    $('fieldset').css('background-color', 'blue');
    $('fieldset').css('margin-top', '0px');
        $('fieldset').css('margin-left', '0px');
   }
    else if(lastsettings == "red"){
        $('fieldset').css('background-color', 'red');
        $('fieldset').css('margin-top', '0px');
        $('fieldset').css('margin-right', '0px');
    }
    else if(lastsettings == "yellow"){
        $('fieldset').css('background-color', 'yellow');
        $('fieldset').css('margin-top', '240px');
        $('fieldset').css('margin-left', '0px');
    }
    else if(lastsettings == "green"){
        $('fieldset').css('background-color', 'green');
        $('fieldset').css('margin-top', '240px');
        $('fieldset').css('margin-right', '0px');
    }

$('select').change(function(){
    $('select option:selected').each(function(){
        position = this.text;

        $('fieldset').css('margin', 'auto');

        if(position == "Top Left"){
            $('fieldset').css('background-color', 'blue');
            $('fieldset').css('margin-top', '0px');
            $('fieldset').css('margin-left', '0px');
            $.cookie('position', 'blue');
        }
        else if(position == "Top Right"){
            $('fieldset').css('background-color', 'red');
            $('fieldset').css('margin-top', '0px');
            $('fieldset').css('margin-right', '0px');
            $.cookie('position', 'red');
        }
        else if(position == "Bottom Left"){
            $('fieldset').css('background-color', 'yellow');
            $('fieldset').css('margin-top', '240px');
            $('fieldset').css('margin-left', '0px');
            $.cookie('position', 'yellow');
        }
        else if(position == "Bottom Right"){
            $('fieldset').css('background-color', 'green');
            $('fieldset').css('margin-top', '240px');
            $('fieldset').css('margin-right', '0px');
            $.cookie('position', 'green');
        }
        else{
            $('fieldset').css('background-color', 'white');
            $('fieldset').css('margin', 'auto');
            $('fieldset').css('margin-top', '100px');
        }

    });

});

        $("#invisibility").toggle(function(){
        $('fieldset').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }, function(){
        $('fieldset').css('visibility', 'visible');
    });

});
```

I'm using the jquery cookie plugin, but when I refresh my page it goes back to normal. I am coding a website where I move a box to a certain location using a fieldset, but when I refresh my page the box moves back to It's original position instead of the position I set it to before the refresh.

Answer (score 0):

well, if you create the cookie `location` like

```
 var lastsettings = $.cookie('location');
```

... then, the next step is to assign a value to such cookie like

```
$.cookie('location', 'blue');
```

... but you are setting the value to a non-existing cookie instead

```
$.cookie('position', 'blue');
```

Comment: `location` and `position` are synonymous but the jQuery cookie plugin doesn't know that ;)

Comment: So should i change every position i have to location?

Comment: Ok thanks the only problem I have now is when I make it go back to center and reload it will lets say I have my box in the top right previously instead of going to the center when i reset it will go to thew top right. Otherwise if I reload it on top right it would stay top right only the center is the problem.

Comment: I just realized that you are also using a var `position` that is conflicting with the cookie so I am afraid you have to reverse all the cookies to `location` ... apologies.